# Should I insulate a garage when converting it to a workshop?

Tags: insulation

I am wanting to convert my garage in to a workshop and i wanted to know how important it is to insulate the walls so i am never working in freezing or roasting conditions.

I am in the UK so our weather isn't usually extreme.

What suggestions on how, or if, i should insulate?

It is breezeblock constructed with brick on the outside. The door is a regular thin metal garage door.

Answer (score 3):

To insulate or not to insulate, that is the question? That would depend on the amount of time you plan on using the room, how tolerant you are to the temperature changes, and what amount of money you would prefer to spend?

Insulating a much used room (especially a work space) is the best way to remain comfortable and focused while occupying it. Insulating your space will also allow you to spend less on the energy it takes to heat or cool it.

Insulating techniques are varied depending on your budget and the material that composes the room. Here in the States building codes are becoming more stringent regarding minimum R- values and were it can be placed. For instance, the IRC states roof  insulation (for rafters) must be a minimum of R-30 (for most N.A. climate zones).

Insulating a room can be as basic as adding weather-stripping to door bottoms and sealing electrical box gaps to the most involved upgrading windows to dual-glazing and adding another layer of attic insulation.

Most everyone would agree that no matter what type of insulation or how basic, in the long run your investment will save you money and increase your comfort-level in that particular room.

Answer (score 1):

My only concern would be if the projects would suffer, if you can handle the extremes. For example, gluing up wood and the glue freezes, or in the summer, applying a clear finish and sweating onto the work. Sanding is made difficult while sweating onto the project, it will make for a really bad finish job... Done that....